# Why does the output = 12?

Tags: python

I don't understand why the output is 12.

```
sum = 0
number = [8,9,6,3]
for grade in number:
    if grade>=9:
        sum = sum + grade
sum = sum + grade
print(sum)
```

Comment: Because `9+3=12`?

Comment: Because 9+3=12.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't really intend to have the `sum = sum + grade` *after* your `for` loop?

Comment: You can use `sum = sum([x for x in number if x >= 9])`

Comment: You should NOT be using `sum` as a variable name, it's a built-in function in Python and you're overwriting it.

Comment: @CeliusStingher that is wrong on many levels. 1: you're reassigning the built-in `sum()` function to a variable name `sum` while also using the function, 2: you're using a list comprehension which wastes memory. You want `sum_of_grades = sum(x for x in number if x >= 9)`.

Comment: I know it shouldn't be used, but that's how op called their desired output and this being discouraged has already been addressed.

Comment: Please limit to use comments that are helpful and address an issue to be solved. If part of the problem has been previously addressed there is no point in repeating. Furthermore, keep in mind that being condescending doesn't make you a better user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should exclude `sum = sum + grade` (line number 6, since you add last value of grade which is `3` on line number 6.) this line in order to get `9`.

Comment: You should discourage OP from using `sum` as a variable name as well.

Comment: I see, removing the line fixed it. Thanks guys!

Comment: @MikaelChan You should upvote and accept Nagmat's answer if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

For a more in-depth answer: the reason you're getting a total of 12 is because of that last line `sum = sum + grade` *after* the `for` loop. An iterator variable always takes every value in an iterable when going through a `for` loop, and therefore the last value in your list `[8, 9, 6, 3]` is the value of `grade` ***even after the*** `for` ***loop ends.***

In addition, to echo what I've been saying in the comments: you should not be using `sum` as the name of your accumulator variable: `sum()` is a built-in function in Python, and by using `sum` as a variable name, you are overwriting that function.

Answer (score 0):

Like Nagmat said, simply delete line 6 to get the correct answer.

To answer your question (why is it twelve?), it's a matter of scope.  The value of grade is being updated with each pass through the FOR loop, eventually winding up on 3 (since that's the last value in the list).  Therefore coming out of the loop, grade is equal to 3 and sum is equal to 9 (since that was the only value greater than or equal to 9).

So when we arrive at line 6 we're now outside the scope of the loop, but python still remembers the terminal value of grade (3).  So it's adding 3 to the as-intended sum (9).